Laravel Sail Docker Permissions Issue: Files Created with Incorrect Ownership and Permissions
I'm experiencing persistent permission issues with my Laravel application running in a Docker container using Laravel Sail. Despite trying various solutions, I can't seem to resolve the problem completely.
Environment

Host OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6
Docker version: 27.2.1
Docker Compose version: v2.29.1-desktop.1
Laravel Sail

The Problem
When I create new files using Artisan commands (e.g., vendor/bin/sail artisan make:view), the files are created with -rw-r--r-- permissions and inconsistent ownership. This causes issues when I try to modify these files later.
What I've Observed
All newly created files are owned by sail:sail when within the container.
All files have -rw-r--r-- permissions.
Here's a sample output:
-rw-r--r-- 1 sail sail   118 Oct 10 22:11 Example21.blade.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 sail sail    63 Oct 10 22:37 Example22.blade.php

Questions

What could be causing this inconsistent behavior with file ownership and permissions?
How can I ensure that all new files are created with the correct ownership (matching my host user, UID 1000) and with writable permissions?
Is there a comprehensive solution that will address both existing files and ensure correct permissions for future files?

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. I'm happy to provide any additional information that might be helpful in resolving this issue.
What I've Tried

Adjusting the WWWUSER and WWWGROUP in my .env file to 1000 to match my UID on my system.
Modifying the docker-compose.yml file to include user mapping.
Creating custom scripts to fix permissions.
Rebuilding and restarting containers multiple times.

Despite these attempts, the core issue persists.

It might be useful for others to add the Dockerfile to the question by editing the question.
